# Cant delete folder after creating it with PyPDF2 - Python 3.10.1 and Django 4.0.6

Tags: python, django, blocking, pypdf

Im creating a folder with PDF Files in it. Im using PyPDF2 in Django. It works all fine, the folder with the files in it is created. But after that, i cant delete it without stopping the running server. It throws an error saying the file is used by another application.

Do anyone know how i can fix that problem?

Here is the code snippet, which creates the folder with the pdf files in it:

```
# Merge Befunde
for folder in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    mergeFile = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
    for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "\\" + folder):
        if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            file = os.getcwd() + "\\" + folder + "\\" + filename
            try:
                mergeFile.append(PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file))
            except:
                print("Error in", file)
        else:
            continue
    mergeFile.write(folder + ".pdf")
    mergeFile.close()
```

Comment: My guess is that a file handle is not closed. Can you pass the file path directly to the merge (hence not create a PdfReader)?

Comment: As a side note: PdfFileMerger is deprecated. Use PdfMerger

Comment: I tried both. It doesnt change anything. But now, it throws a warning message: "PdfReadWarning: startxref on same line as offset"

Comment: Maybe this warning caused that the file is not closed properly?

Comment: The warning does not affect if files are closed

Comment: Can you pass the file path directly to the merger? I'm pretty sure that is the issue.

Comment: Do you use Windows, Linux, or Mac?

Comment: Hey, im sorry i worked on other issues the last month, so i forgot to look in this feed. Im using windows 10.

Comment: I still have the same problem. I tried to pass the file directly to the merger, but the result was the same. I found out that there is a process named python.exe, which is locking the file. I want to handle the issue without killing this particular process.

Comment: Which version of PyPDF2 do you use? (add a `print(PyPDF2.__version__`)

Comment: The Version is 2.6.0

Comment: Do you mind updating to the latest version (2.10.5) and testing again?

Comment: I tried, but it shows the same behaviour. I found out that there is this Warning "startxref on same line as offset"

Comment: And i can delete the files that are created, the folder above throws the error that another user is locking this file/folder

Comment: First i create with os.mkdir a folder. After that i copy and merge files in this folder. The files can be renamed and deleted. Tha Folder im creating before cant be deleted or renamed. Is there a Problem with the os module?

Comment: I will post the code in a now post

Answer (score 0):

I found out that maybe the problem is not with the files im creating with the PyPDF2 Library.

First im reating a folder with the os module. After that i copy and create some PDF files in it. After finishing i want to rename or move the folder, but it throws an error that this file is being used by another user.
But i can delete or rename the files i have created **in** the folder. After i stop the django server the problem does not occur and i can do anything i want.

```
    try:
        os.mkdir(folder_name)  
    except OSError as error:
        pass
    shutil.copy(path, dest)  

    newname = f"{x['parent_id']}_{x['prob_nr']}_{parameter}.pdf"  
    
    os.rename(dest + "\\" + datei, dest+ "\\" + newname)  


# Merge Befunde
for folder in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    mergeFile = PyPDF2.PdfMerger()
    for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd() + "\\" + folder):
        if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            file = os.getcwd() + "\\" + folder + "\\" + filename
            try:
                mergeFile.append(file)
            except:
                print("Error in", file)
        else:
            continue
    mergeFile.write(folder + ".pdf")
    mergeFile.close()
```

Comment: I solved the problem after a week :))
Tha problem was that the os module was still pointing at this folder. i changed the diretory to os.chdir("/") and the problem was gone :))

Comment: I would be VERY surprised if the os module really is the issue

Comment: I dont know if the os module itself was the issue, but it was the solution. python.exe locked the folder i created before and i solved the problem with changing the current directory with os.chdir("/")